# ngx-bootstrap dropdown alignment not working when setting dynamic class

Tags: angular, dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I have an odd issue with the ngx-bootstrap (using bootstrap 4.1) dropdown component.

I'm setting the dropdown menu to align to the right via a variable, however, when I do this the dropdown only aligns right on the second click.

Here is a sample code that replicates the issue:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown placement="bottom right">
    <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      This dropdown's menu is right-aligned <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{'dropdown-menu-right': true}" role="menu">
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note: the [ngClass] where I'm dynamically setting the attribute is what is causing the issue, if I put this statically in the class definition it works fine.

Here is a sample Plunker that replicates:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5OrrQx0uefrWxWBliJDL?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the generated html in the debugger, you'll see that the `ul` contains your `dropdown-menu-right` class AND some inline styles, which override the positionning (the first time you open it). These inline styles are probably added by the library.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu show dropdown-menu-right" 
role="menu" ng-reflect-klass="dropdown-menu" 
ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" 
style="left: 0px; right: auto; top: 100%; transform: translateY(0px);">
```

Maybe you should take the issue to github with the library maintainers. As a workaround, you could try adding this css to your global CSS file

```
.dropdown-menu-right {
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important; 
}
```

This is the same style defined by default for that class, except that there is the `important` rule

[Your plunker edited](https://plnkr.co/edit/YW0wLtd9ewt9UKfSK7j8?p=preview) (with style in index.html)

Comment: David. Thanks very much for that explanation, and your workaround works perfectly.  I'll raise a issue with the ngx-bootstrap team.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I think this is some kind of ngx-bootstrap lifecycle bug.

What does fix it for me is the following ugly piece of "templating magic" (`popupLeft` being my boolean, that determines whether `dropdown-menu-right` should be added or not):

```html
  <ng-template *ngIf="popupLeft" dropdownMenu>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dropdownMenuContents"></ng-container>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template *ngIf="!popupLeft" dropdownMenu>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dropdownMenuContents"></ng-container>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #dropdownMenuContents>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <!-- ... -->
    </li>
  </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make `placement="bottom right"` work, you should also add `container="body"`

This should work:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown container="body" placement="bottom right">
    <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      This dropdown's menu is right-aligned <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{'dropdown-menu-right': true}" role="menu">
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this wrap entire expression with single quotes `'`   `[ngClass]="'{dropdown-menu-right: true}'"` 
instead of this `[ngClass]="{'dropdown-menu-right': true}"`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, however this doesn't work.  Wrapping it like this just sets the whole class to the value '{dropdown-menu-right: true}', which just leaves it aligning left.  I'm trying to set the class to 'dropdown-menu-right' when a dynamic value is true.